# Can I get a transit visa on arrival in Istanbul?

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, rwanda

I am a Rwandese national, planning to travel to Macedonia but will need to stop in Istanbul for a short while to pick up my Macedonian visa.

Will it be possible for me to get a Turkish transit visa on arrival?

Comment: The info you need is here: https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/

Comment: @MastaBaba can you maybe turn that into an answer?

Comment: @MarkMayo: As you wish. Though I feel that so many questions on here are about Turkish visas that this question is possibly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

All the info you need on requiring and getting visas for Turkey is [here](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).

Comment: Please consider expanding that answer a bit as links are unrealiable and can go down at any moment.

Comment: Come on. I had it has a comment, was asked to make it an answer, and now it's not good as an answer. Feel free to edit it, though.